# Fundamental Background for western humanities

Tags: humanities

For an engineer, knowing some math is critical. What about modern humanities which is mostly western humanities? Which resources you recommend?

Comment: "the humanities" is way too broad for there to be any single critical thing.

Comment: Do you mean which of the Humanities are important for an Engineer to know? I think that might be answerable - there's one or two particular fields that would be important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many universities teach a course in Western Civilization. The textbook for such a course might help. Likewise something in the history of philosophy that is western (Greek and thereafter) might work.

It depends on what you mean by "The Humanities". It is pretty broad with many specializations: Philosophy, History, Religion, etc. etc.